# Knockout js copy of observableArray

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

How to make copy of `self.items` and place values in `self.copy`? I tried to do `self.copy(self.items.slice());` but it does not work

```js
function MyViewModel() {
        var self = this;
        self.items = ko.observableArray();
        self.copy = ko.observableArray();
        self.items.push({ id: 1, name: 'Jhon' });
        self.items.push({ id: 2, name: 'Smith' });
        self.copy(self.items.slice());
        self.alarm = function (data) {
            var itemsWithSameId = self.copy().filter(function (item) {
                return item.id === data.id;
            });
            var theItem = itemsWithSameId[0];
            debugger;
        }
    }
    
    ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/2.0.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Passenger name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: items">
        <tr>
            <td><input class="target" data-bind="value: name, event: { change: $root.alarm}" /></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What are you expecting to see that is not happening?

Comment: for example if i am changing in first input 'Jhon' to 'Jhonn'. I expect to get in 'theItem' name 'Jhon'.

Comment: But 'theItem' should show old value. Value that was before new input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when you copy an object, you're copying references rather than data. Using `slice` is good for dealing with arrays if the contents are not objects, but yours are.

What you can do is use `ko.toJS` to make a deep copy (as long as you're just interested in comparing non-object members).

```js
function MyViewModel() {
        var self = this;
        self.items = ko.observableArray();
        self.copy = ko.observableArray();
        self.items.push({ id: 1, name: 'Jhon' });
        self.items.push({ id: 2, name: 'Smith' });
        self.copy(ko.toJS(self.items()));
        self.alarm = function (data) {
            var itemsWithSameId = self.copy().filter(function (item) {
                return item.id === data.id;
            });
            var theItem = itemsWithSameId[0];
            debugger;
        }
    }
    
    ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/2.0.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Passenger name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: items">
        <tr>
            <td><input class="target" data-bind="value: name, event: { change: $root.alarm}" /></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```